# ROS Answers SE migration: full ros api?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can i get the full ros api documentation? i found few but them seems not to be complete. like [this](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rosnode/html/frames.html) one and also [this](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/index.html) one. But them do not seem to contain all the inofrmation of all the ros classes and modules. Also why is rtt_ros_integration package related api is not present? I am asking so that i can browser through all the ros classes and use them if needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286490/full-ros-api-?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-25**:
What is the "full ROS API"? C++ packages come with auto-generated Doxygen API documentation, but the usefullness of that depends on whether the author has spent some time on it. Python packages can also be accompanied by auto-generated docs, but again, will depend on the author spending time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-25**:\

> Also why is rtt_ros_integration package related api is not present?

`rtt_ros_integration` is a metapackage. They don't contain any code, so there is no documentation generated ..

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-25**:
ROS is not one library, it is many packages, each with a separate repository and maintainer, and each of which can be installed separately.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-25**:
o o,, ya, now i realize..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/) but it's not user freidly to use i think.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2018-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0